# Finding Correct Regular Expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

what i am trying to find is the correct regular expression

```
import re

line = "The Boeing AH-64 Apache is an American four-blade,"

print(re.findall('(A.+)\s', line))
```

this is want i want

```
    ['AH-64', 'Apache' , 'American']
```

and this is what i'm getting

```
['AH-64 Apache is an American']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a word boundary (`\b`) before `A` and then match one or more non-whitespace chars after it (`\S+`):

```
import re
line = "The Boeing AH-64 Apache is an American four-blade,"
print(re.findall(r'\bA\S+', line))
```

**NOTE**: to match `A` as a whole word, replace `+` (1 or more occurrences) with `*` (0 or more occurrences): `r'\bA\S*'`. I assume you want to match longer sequences though.

Or, since `\S` matches all symbols and punctuation, you may precise your regex a bit and use

```
print(re.findall(r'\bA[\w-]+', line))
```

where `[\w-]+` matches 1 or more letter, digits, `_` and `-` symbols.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/a4mKkI) showing `['AH-64', 'Apache', 'American']` output.

Comment: i did not know about \b and \w , can you please link the cheat sheet you're following , and once again thanks my friend

Comment: and i found the very small mistake in my expression , (A\S+)\s which means start extracting data starting with 'A' with any non-blank character that follows it , stop extracting after you find a space

originally i wrote (A.+)\s which meant all characters that follow 'A'

Comment: @ShubhamDebnath If you use `(A.+)\s` it will match any `A` and then any 1+ chars as many as possible up to the last whitespace and the whitespace is required. I have no cheatsheet, I just know regex syntax in many languages. If you want to learn the basics, do the exercises [here](https://regexone.com/). Then, there are http://regular-expressions.info and http://rexegg.com - you may find all about regex there.